# jquery slider animation playing fast after window is minimized

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, timeout, slider

I'm using coda slider for a website and unfortunately after the window is minimized, the content slider plays super fast. I know it has something to do with Set time out, but I could not achieve perfect result yet. Any help on this will be appreciated. My script code is:

```
    var theInt = null;
    var $crosslink, $navthumb;
    var curclicked = 0;

    theInterval = function(cur){
        clearInterval(theInt);

        if( typeof cur != 'undefined' )
            curclicked = cur;

        $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
        $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
            $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');

        theInt = setInterval(function(){
            $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
            $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
            $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');
            curclicked++;
            if( 4 == curclicked )
                curclicked = 0;

        }, 8000);
        setTimeout( nextCycle, 2000 );
    };

    $(function(){

        $("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();

        $navthumb = $(".nav-thumb");
        $crosslink = $(".cross-link");

        $navthumb
        .click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            theInterval($this.parent().attr('href').slice(1) - 1);
            return false;
        });

        theInterval();
    });
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Java.  Tag removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always run into problems with setTimeout. My method is to do something like the following:

`var timer = setTimeout( function(){nextCycle();}, 2000 );`

Comment: Thanks Kyle, but after I placed the code in, it still does not work. I'm kind of new to Jquery. so I will appreciate if you could tell me where and how should I implement it. Thanks.

Comment: Is your project publicly available? Can you post a link?

Comment: Unfortunately not. this is the slider i'm working on : [link](http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-slick-auto-playing-featured-content-slider/) but I just noticed this one works ok, I think I have included a newer version of Jquery into my project because the old one removes functionality of some other parts like pop up light box. I assume it has something to do with the Jquery version. I just need to know where to place the code.

Comment: Replace your existing setTimeout... `setTimeout( nextCycle, 2000 );` about the 25th line down in the code you provided

Comment: I placed it here: if( 4 == curclicked )
     curclicked = 0;
     setTimeout( nextCycle, 2000 );
    
   }, 8000);  but no luck. Could you please be more specific after which phrase shall I paste it?

Comment: @DaveHomer Im sorry, but I can't help you any further without having some sort of demo of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the library is colliding with another library I'm using. I used another function which when the browser window is minimized or tab is changed on coming back to the page to refresh the page, in this case, all the scripts will reload and the slider will start from beginning. Though it is better if I could do it without refreshing the whole page and only by refreshing the scripts, or by playing the slider from the beginning somehow, but unfortunately my javascript knowledge is not much! here is the code:

```
     $(window).blur(function() {
//Do Nothing//   
});

$(window).focus(function() {
//This refreshes the whole page //
       location.reload();
});
```